# Need first Item of array but just get first letter

Tags: python, arrays, list

Hello I have a problem I have a list and I need the first Items of it. I sounds simple but I cant find out the solution. In the list is the first item always a number but i dont know how long the number is so it could be a 54 or a 761. This a example code:

```
for title1 in soup.select('h1'):
    title.append('645')
    title.append(*[title1.get_text(strip=True)]) 
with open('title.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
        for row in title:
            print(row[0])
```

The problem is if I do it like this it just gives the first letter.

Comment: Your `title` looks to be a `list` of `str`s, so each `row` represents the iterated `str`, where you slice it by `[0]` so you get the first index of the `str`.  Perhaps you meant to `row.split` it by some delimiter? What does `get_text` return? Start thinking from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are accessing the first term of each element in the title list.
when you use :

```
 for row in title
```

it iterates each item in that list automatically so you don't have to use *row[0]* to access the first element.
Here, i have fixed the code for you:

```
for title1 in soup.select('h1'):
    title.append('645')
    title.append(*[title1.get_text(strip=True)]) 
with open('title.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
        for row in title:
            print(row)
```

But this code of yours would output everything in that list so i ask yopu to use the following code in order to get only the first element.

```
for title1 in soup.select('h1'):
    title.append('645')
    title.append(*[title1.get_text(strip=True)]) 
with open('title.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
        print(title[0])
```

Happy coding...:):):)